# Extract photo from Live Photo

Tags: photos

I recently backed up all my iPhone 6s photos to my media server (running Linux).  All of the Live Photo files are in a ".mov" format.  They play fine as videos, but I'd like to extract the high quality photo from each file.  I tried inspecting the file with `ffprobe` but that didn't give me much to go on

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_1419.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-02-10 22:27:35
  Duration: 00:00:01.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9355 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1440x1080, 8637 kb/s, 11.59 fps, 15 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-10 22:27:35
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-10 22:27:35
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 43 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-10 22:27:35
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Is it possible for me to extract the photo on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo isn't stored within the video. The phone creates a photo and video separately which can be pulled separately off the device using Image Capture's equivalent on Windows or Linux.